# How can I init h2o and train data in java?

Tags: java, h2o

I saw the examples of how to init h2o and use it in python.

```
import h2o;
h2o.init();
h2o.train_gbm(**);
```

But how can I init h2o and use it in java?
Is there any example code or document?

Comment: Use REST http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/faq/java.html

Comment: I know I can call rest api in java, but how to init h2o like h2o.init() in java?